# ASP.NET MVC 3 AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a project using ASP.NET MVC 3, now use a MembershipProvider, RoleProvider AuthorizeAttribute and custom. So in certain parts of the code use this:

```
[Logon(Roles = "login, test1")]
```

This code works perfectly, for use in the MembershipProvider code:

```
public override string [] GetRolesForUser (string username)
{
    var = UsuarioRepository.GetListaPermissoesByUsuarioEmail permissions (username);

    if (permissions == null)
    {
        nullPermissao var = new string [0];
        nullPermissao return;
    }

    return permissions;
}
```

My question is. how can I use the following code, which method will need to customize?
I want to check is determined whether a particular type of user who is logged in and if it has certain privileges.

```
[Logon(Roles = "login, test1," Users = "User1")]
```

Using override string [] GetRolesForUser (string username) method it checks the Roles, in wich method I can check the User?

Comment: Are you trying to restrict access to a method to a specific user?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I type it in a wrong way, actually is "Logon" a custom attribute I created from AuthorizeAttribute class.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. What's the relation between the Logon attribute and the GetRolesForUser method you have shown?

Comment: I want to check is determined whether a particular type of user who is logged in and if it has certain privileges.

Comment: And what's wrong with `[Logon(Roles = "login, test1," Users = "User1")]`? This is checking that the user must have the `login` and `test1` role in order to access the action. Also only `User1` can access it.

Comment: Using override string [] GetRolesForUser (string username) method it checks the Roles, in wich method I can check the User?

Comment: Are you asking about a method inside your custom `LogonAttribute` in which you would have access to the currently logged in user? By the way could you please show the code for this custom attribute because it is absolutely unclear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work out of the box with the AuthorizeAttribute. It checks if HttpContext.User.Identity.Name matches any of the terms you defined under AuthorizeAttribute.Users

As i see from the comments, you rolled your own LogonAttribute where your probably overwrote the OnAuthorize method. This is where the AuthorizeAtrribute does it`s magic.

*Original ASP.NET MVC Source*

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
  if (httpContext == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
  IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
  return user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && (this._usersSplit.Length <= 0 || Enumerable.Contains<string>((IEnumerable<string>) this._usersSplit, user.Identity.Name, (IEqualityComparer<string>) StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (this._rolesSplit.Length <= 0 || Enumerable.Any<string>((IEnumerable<string>) this._rolesSplit, new Func<string, bool>(user.IsInRole)));
}

public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  if (filterContext == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
  if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive((ControllerContext) filterContext))
    throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
  if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
  {
    HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
    cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(this.CacheValidateHandler), (object) null);
  }
  else
    this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use the following?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "login, test1", Users = "User1")]
```

Comment: Using override string [] GetRolesForUser (string username) method it checks the Roles, in wich method I can check the User?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking but that's the right attribute to use and then you can override the default role and membership providers to have custom ways of controlling your users and roles other than the default aspnet database tables. You have to update the web.config to use the alternate providers though too.